# Convert JPEG byte[] to NV21 byte[]

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to convert JPEG byte[] data from Camera.PictureCallback to NV21 byte[] format but it didn't work.

I try to do this:

```
byte [] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {
    int [] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];
    scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    byte [] yuv = new byte[inputWidth*inputHeight*3/2];
    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    scaled.recycle();
    return yuv;
}

void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
            Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
            U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some news about it ? Can you post the solution if you find it ?